# div variable inaccessible due to its protection level in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am getting the error while building code file in vb.net. The '#divvariable' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Code snippet:

In ascx file:

```
<div id="SampleFormWrapper" runat="server">  
</div>
```

In vb file:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            SampleFormWrapper.Visible = True
        End If
        End If
    Catch exc As Exception        'Module failed to load
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Not seeing `#divvariable` in your posted code.  And did you really mean to have to `End If`s in your code behind?

Answer (score 0):

As Tim said, you have 2 "End If" tags. But most important, have you declared the "SampleFormWrapper"? You need to declare it in your .vb file first if you want to use it and get the div from your .ascx using GetElementById().

Maybe that can help you